# Why can I infere that TRUE == FALSE in php?

Tags: php

A friend of mine recently showed my the following snippet

```
<?php
    $a = 0;
    $b = 'x';
    if(FALSE == $a && $a == $b && $b == TRUE) {
         echo 'WTF!?';
    }
?>
```

which ouputs `WTF!?`

I understand why `FALSE == $a` holds, because zero is considered to be `FALSE`. I also understand why `$b == TRUE` holds, because the string is not empty. But I didn't understand why `$a == $b` is true, could somebody explain to me what type coercion rules play together here to get this rather amusing result?

Comment: Because $a is an integer, $b is being converted to an integer before comparison ... and `(int) 'x' == 0`

Comment: Just like Hanky said, you should wrap them in a bracket

Answer (score 4):

when you compare `$a == $b` you are comparing an `int` with a `string` so `PHP` tries to parse the string into an int if it fails which happened in this case, it changes its value to 0 and then `0 == 0` returns `true`. Check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically. These rules also apply to the switch statement. The type conversion does not take place when the comparison is === or !== as this involves comparing the type as well as the value.

Change this condition `$a == $b` to `$a === $b` to compare the type as well. Hope this helps.